# Allow HTML content to extend past parent's width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to modify content on my site to lower the characters per line without changing the font size. To do this, I want to make the content container width lower. Currently the width is 984px and I am going to lower it to 757px.

The problem I have is images with the content. All the images are inside divs or figure elements inside the content element. I still need the images to have a max-width of 984px. Is there a way I can solve this with just CSS or will I need jQuery as well?

Here is an example of some code. The content is from a course and there are a lot of them so it is not feasible to edit all the course content. I need to take the existing styles to make these changes.

```
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="course-heading">Driver Bearings</h2>
    <p class="course-content" style="margin-left: 80px;">The unit uses both oil and grease lubricated bearings: the drive (top) bearings use oil while the bearings at the opposite end (bottom) use grease. A closeup view of the top oil fill and drain can be viewed here:</p>
    <div>
        <img alt="Oil Bearing Lubrication" class="course-image" src="/digi-oilView-01.png">
    </div>
    <p class="course-caption">Oil Bearing Lubrication</p>
</div>
```

Also, all content should be centered on the page.

Comment: just because the image is not 984px doesnt mean thats its max with is not still 984px...that would be an issue with the current width like using a percentage improperly

Comment: add the width:757px to the p.course-content{} only

Comment: There are a lot more elements that would need that width and they have different margins. The editor I have to create the content uses margins for indents. So I would need to convert the left margin to left padding as well. I was hoping just modifying the image styling would be easier.

Comment: If your containing element (.content) has the width adjustment, and overflow: visible, you should be okay. No positioning required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to set a `height` so it doesn't adjust to include all the content.

### HTML

```
<div class="content">
     <h2 class="course-heading">Driver Bearings</h2>

    <p class="course-content" style="margin-left: 80px;">The unit uses both oil and grease lubricated bearings: the drive (top) bearings use oil while the bearings at the opposite end (bottom) use grease. A closeup view of the top oil fill and drain can be viewed here:</p>
    <div class="img-container">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/950x150"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="course-caption">Oil Bearing Lubrication</p>
    <div class="img-container">
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/950x150"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="course-caption">Oil Bearing Lubrication</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.content {
    background-color:black;
    width:768px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.img-container > div {
    position:relative;
}
.img-container img {
    position:absolute;
    width:950px;
}

body {
    background-color:yellow;
    color:grey;
    width:1050px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

### JS

```
$(".img-container").each(function () {
    $(this).css('height', $(this).children()[0].children[0].height + 'px');

});

$(".img-container > div > img").each(function () {
    var paddingValue = (Number($(".content").css('width').substring(0, $(".content").css('width').length - 2)) - this.width) / 2;
    $(this).parent().css('left', paddingValue);
});
```

*** Body `color` set obviously just so you can see content outside parent and also `background-color` on `.content` ***

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmep9w6c/20/ *** UPDATED ***

Comment: The image and image div are in the content div so they still have a max-width of 768px. I need them to be able to be larger. Many of the images are 950px wide.

Comment: Oh, so not extend in height but width as well.  Gotcha

Comment: @Sean Ok, fixed.  It can extend past in width.

Comment: The image isn't always the last element on the page so if there is more content below the image, it will be hidden by the image.

Comment: @Sean Ok, I added jQuery code to modify the height of the img-container to push content down.

Comment: @Sean just need to do the same thing for padding-left to make sure the image is centered on the page.

Comment: I was hoping for a CSS only solution but I don't think it exists. I will try your jQuery solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Sean for my own benefit I centered all items and applied the `left` to images using jQuery so this is complete now (edited JSFiddle in answer).

Comment: @Sean Sorry now it is updated, included different size images to show it working as well.